# MVC4 mobile app background image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, background-image

This should be simple, but I cannot get it to work. Its MVC 4 mobile application. No changes were applied to layout or CSS at this point. All is needed is to add a background image (the same one for every page). Where and how do i do this? I assume I need to add something to the `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Just to add to this. I can change the font of the page by editting the Site.css 'body' element. yet no matter what i do to the background, nothing will change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC if you want to add background to your page then go to

```
\yourappname\Content\Site.css
```

and under body tag you can add your background image which will be same for every page.